# Getting Data Lake Metadata in Azure Data Factory's Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, derived-column

I want to add the timestamp of copying parquet files to my dataframe in data flow as a derived column.
In source module I can filter parquet **files by last modified** which makes me think that it should be possible to access files' metadata including copied timestamp through derived column transformations, but I couldn't find anything for it in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions).
[image]

Comment: There is currently no way to get the last modified timestamp along with the file name that is read from a folder. There is an upcoming capability called browse transformation which will help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function can get the last modified time in the data flow expression.

As a workaround, you can create a Get Metadata activity to get that and then pass it's value to a parameter in your data flow.

[image]

The expression:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified`

[image]

Comment: It would be tough if the folder is large files and we have to loop through them to determine the max of last_modified